# How to put footer view at the bottom of collectionView?

Tags: uicollectionview, footer

I have collectionView, and I need to have a footer view at the bottom of collectionView. When I'm adding UICollectionReusableView it looks like as "current footer". But I need as "footer2".
[image]

Please say is there a way to put footer view at the bottom of collectionView